# Using std::shared_ptr in pointer to pointer scenario

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, c++17, smart-pointers

I've created a `Node` struct to be used in an implementation of binary search tree. It uses shared pointers to keep track of its children:

```
template <class T> struct Node;

template <class T>
using Node_ptr = std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>;

template <class T>
struct Node {
  Node_ptr<T> left;
  Node_ptr<T> right;
  const T label;
  ...
};
```

Now, I'd like to have a function which given some subtree and a value will return either the node of that specific value or the place where such node should be located in future - `find_node`.

This is how it looks at the moment:

```
template <class T>
auto* find_node(Node_ptr<T>* node, const T& value) {
  for (; *node && (*node)->label != value
       ; node = value < (*node)->label ? &(*node)->left : &(*node)->right);

  return node;
}
```

Pretty bad. But it works:

```
template <class T>
class Binary_search_tree {
public:
  // correctly inserts consecutive values
  void insert(const T& value) {
    if (auto* node = find_node(&root, value); !*node)
      *node = std::make_shared<Node<T>>(value);
  }
  ...
private:
  Node_ptr<T> root;
  ...
};
```

I could rewrite `find_node` to use `std::shared_ptr<Node_ptr<T>>` instead of `Node_ptr<T>*` but it would look even worse. Or would it?

How should I handle such situations?

edit: As it's been pointed out, the function can be simplified a bit by taking a reference to starting node, and returning a reference to a node:

```
template <class T>
Node_ptr<T>& find_node(Node_ptr<T>& node_ref, const T& value) {
  auto* node = &node_ref;
  ...
  return *node;
}
```

Comment: Since you're not directly allocating the `Node_ptr<T> *` what you're doing may seem "pretty bad", but it also *works*, I see no reason to wrap shared pointers around shared pointers in this case. Had you  been allocating and storing pointers to shared pointers, that would change things. All of that said, any reason you're not using a *reference* return type? I see no means in which `node` would ever be NULL in the case you're presenting. In fact, the passed `node` would also be a reference candidate.

Comment: Do you really need `shared_ptr` here? Do you share *nodes* between different trees or something?

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks! Indeed, both starting node and the returned one can by passed by reference. I've completely overlooked this fact, being more focused on function's body. But as you have pointed out, in the way raw pointers are used there, they pose no risks usually associated with them. Maybe I'm just digging too deep :)

Comment: If you don't share notes between trees or allow to insert one and the same node multiple times into a single tree, you'd profit from smart pointers only in one single situation (node deletion), whereas you have quite some overhead for nothing in all other situations (insertion, moving nodes e. g. for tree balancing, ...) as you wouldn't actually share pointers apart from modifying the tree (where all involved nodes are known anyway...). So maybe `std::unique_ptr` is a better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use of a raw pointer is suggested when you have to allow for passing a null pointer - not true in your example; or when you have to pass a non-integral value (true in your case).  In the latter case one should still consider passing a reference rather than a raw pointer.  This is a generic suggestion - so exceptions may exist.
2. Having noted that, you could still use a raw pointer in your function here rather safely by making find_node(...) a private function while keeping the insert(...) public. That is safe, since there is no chance of leaving the pointer dangling from inside insert(...).

Essentially we need to guard against two possibilities with raw pointers: #1. prematurely deleting the memory the pointer points to, #2. never deleting the memory that the pointer points to.  Neither of this is possible inside your insert(...) function.  So you're safe.

On a related note, you might consider having unique_pointer for your nodes when they are created and then converting them into shared pointers if they are to be shared by more child than one: std::move(...).